# Send Jquery Array to PHP to then insert in a mySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I need to send an array made of multiple forms entries to PHP to then insert into a mySQL database. I just have no idea how to do that and i can't seem to follow any other instructions online since they're all different to mine.

```
//This is the code used to create the array in Jquery of multiple form entries  
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var called = 0;
            ajax_recaller = function(report){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: report[called].serialize(),
                    url: report[called].attr('action'),
                    success: function(data) {
                        called++;
                        if(called < report.length) {
                            ajax_recaller(report);
                        }
                        else {
                            called=0;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            $(document).on('click','.submitforms',function(){
                var x=0;
                $('.ajax_form').each(function(){
                    report[x] = $(this);
                    x++;
                });
            });

            // 'report' is an array of every expense that has been submitted - it now needs to somehow be stored inside the database

        });
    </script>
```

What i'm hoping is to happen is that each index of the array is able to be submitted to the mySQL database as a new entry